# Android soundpool unexpectedly making the application close with no message when lots of sounds played

Tags: android, soundpool

In my application I have a makesound(int) method that is called when i want sounds to be made at different stages of the game.
I have created the audiomanager and soundpool variable public and intialized the sound pool and the audio manager in the OnCreate method.

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(this.AUDIO_SERVICE);
soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

My makesound(int) method is below

```
 private void makeSound(int w){
    if(onVolume) {    //onvolume is a public boolean var that is set    
        final int volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
        int id;
        switch(w){
            case 1:
                id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.metalimpact, 1);
                break;
            case 2:
                id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swoosh, 1);
                break;
            case 3:
                id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.win, 1);
            case 4:
                id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.win, 1);//second chance
                break;
            case 5:
                id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.fanfare, 1);//second chance
                break;
            default:id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.metalimpact, 1);
        }
        final int soundID = id;

        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {

            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                       int status) {

                soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 0, 0, 1f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This was working fine when I had just one sound to be played. But after I set the switch case stmt and had a lot of sounds playing, I noticed that the application would run fine for sometime, but suddenly crash with no message or anything. Am i loading the Soundpool too much?..Please let me know what i'm doing wrong. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong way to implement your logic.

**Firstly** You are not required to load sounds each time in makeSound(int w) method. Instead Load all sound first and then manage them whether they are loaded or not in LoadCompleteListener.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer >loadedSound=new Map<>();
loadedSound.put(1,soundPool.load(this, R.raw.metalimpact, 1));
loadedSound.put(2,soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swoosh, 1)); 
loadedSound.put(3,soundPool.load(this, R.raw.win, 1));  
loadedSound.put(4,soundPool.load(this, R.raw.win, 1));
loadedSound.put(5,soundPool.load(this, R.raw.fanfare,1));
```

Now you have soundIds return by load method,use then to play sound as

```
switch(w)
{
  case w: soundPool.play(loadedSound.get(w), volume, volume, 0, 0, 1f);
  break;
  default:soundPool.play(loadedSound.get(1), volume, volume, 0, 0, 1f);
}
```